# How to let Gmail forget a name and e-mail address association?

Tags: gmail

In Google Apps I re-issued the e-mail address of a former colleague to a new colleague with the same first name (our format is `firstname@domain`), but now every time I want to compose a message to the new colleague the wrong (old) name is associated with the e-mail address.

**Note:** the name has been changed in the settings of the new account of course :) It's just that my "local" Gmail client keeps autocompleting the wrong name when I type the e-mail address.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your browser which has saved the information in its auto-complete data?

Comment: @pnuts "local" as in that it's my account. I meant the web app of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently all it took was updating the name in my Google Contacts, which apparently uses the e-mail address as the primary key :-/ Never used Google Contacts before, so I completely missed that.